# Apply the maximum and minimum modulus theorems - Why/How?

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the question I have to answer for context, please don't solve the whole problem for me!

> Suppose $|a_k| < R$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. Prove that (unless $|a_k|=0$ for all $k$), $\sqrt[n]{|z-a_1|\cdot |z-a_2| \cdots |z-a_n|}$ assumes a maximum value greater than $R$, and a minimum value less than $R$, at some points $z$ on $|z|=R$. Hint: Apply the maximum and minimum modulus theorems to $\prod_{k=1}^n (R^2-\overline{a_k}z)$.

So the maximum for $|z| \leq R$ is where $|z| = R$, so we set $z = Re^{i\theta}$ and rewrite the "Hint" function as $\prod R|e^{i\theta} - \frac{R}{\overline{a_k}}|$, but I dont see how we can show the maximum is always greater than R! Surely its possible that $|e^{i\theta} - \frac{R}{\overline{a_k}}| = R^{-1}$ or smaller!

Comment: the maximum modulus theorem states that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic on a closed path-connected subset $U$ then its maximum (modulus) lies on the boundary of $U$. the minimum modulus theorem is the same applied to $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ if $f(z) \ne 0$ on $U$ (hint : $U$ can have weird shapes)

Comment: I simply dont understand the use of this. Our functions are holomorphic everywhere from what I can tell, so if you consider it with $|z| \leq R$, then the max must be where $|z| = R$, but I don't see it helpful to show that the maximum value is always greater than R. 

I've considered the "Hint" function with $z = Re^{i\theta}$, but its not clear to me then that you cant select some $\{a_k\}$ such that the maximum is less than R.

Comment: try and see what you get

Comment: Try selecting $\{a_k\}$? With $z= Re^{i\theta}$ you get $\prod R(R - \overline{a_k}e^{i\theta}) =R^n \prod (R - \overline{a_k}e^{i\theta})$, but I'm not convinced you cant select some $\{a_k\}$ such that $|\prod (R - \overline{a_k}e^{i\theta})| < R^{-n + 1}$

Comment: @user1952009 Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: @user1952009 I believe this is $\prod R| e^{i\theta} - \frac{R}{\overline{a_k}} |$, but since $|\frac{R}{\overline{a_k}}| > 1$ couldn't $|e^{i\theta} - \frac{R}{\overline{a_k}} | = R^{-1}$ (or smaller)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is here:
[Show that $\sqrt[k]{|z-a_1|\cdots |z-a_k|}$ has a max greater than $R$, and a min less than $R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302606/show-that-sqrtkz-a-1-cdots-z-a-k-has-a-max-greater-than-r-and-a-mi?rq=1)

You don't actually need to convert $z = e^{\theta i} $ form.

Let $f(z) = \left| z - a _ { 1 } \right| \cdot \left| z - a _ { 2 } \right| \cdots \left| z - a _ { n } \right|$. You want to show that there exists a point in $|z| \leq R$ where $f(z) = R$. For instance, $f(0)$. If you plug $z = 0$ into $\prod _ { k = 1 } ^ { n } \left( R ^ { 2} - \overline { a _ { k } } z \right)$ since they are equivalent expressions, you will find that $|R^n|f(0) = \prod _ { k = 1 } ^ { n }  R ^ { 2 } = R^{2n} \implies f(0) = R^n$. So the function you care about is $g(z) = f(z)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, which means that $g(0) = R$. $z = 0$, however is not the boundary. So by Min/Max Mod Theorem, there must be a minimum or a maximum on the boundary such that it is less than/greater than $R$ and we are done.