# Proving the maximum where $|z| = R$ is greater than R

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the question I have to answer for context, please don't solve the whole problem for me!

> Suppose $|a_k| < R$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. Prove that (unless $|a_k|=0$ for all $k$), $\sqrt[n]{|z-a_1|\cdot |z-a_2| \cdots |z-a_n|}$ assumes a maximum value greater than $R$, and a minimum value less than $R$, at some points $z$ on $|z|=R$. Hint: Apply the maximum and minimum modulus theorems to $\prod_{k=1}^n (R^2-\overline{a_k}z)$.

So the maximum for $|z| \leq R$ is where $|z| = R$, so we set $z = Re^{i\theta}$ and rewrite the "Hint" function as $\prod R|e^{i\theta} - \frac{R}{\overline{a_k}}|$, but I dont see how we can show the maximum is always greater than R! Surely its possible that $|e^{i\theta} - \frac{R}{\overline{a_k}}| = R^{-1}$ or smaller!

Am I on the totally wrong track for proving this? I'm absolutely stuck.

Comment: Here is a related post: [Show that $\sqrt[k]{|z-a_1|\cdots |z-a_k|}$ has a max greater than $R$, and a min less than $R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/302606)