# Show that $\left|\dfrac{R(z-a)}{R^{2}-\overline{a}z}\right|$ is analytic for $|z| \leq R$, and maps the circle $|z| = R$ into the unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

> a) Suppose $|a| < R$, show that
>   $$\left|\dfrac{R(z-a)}{R^{2}-\overline{a}z}\right|$$ is analytic for $|z| \leq
>  R$, and maps the circle $|z| = R$ into the unit circle.
>
> b) Suppose $|a_k| <R$ for $k=1,2,...,n$. Prove that (unless $|a_k| =
>  0$ for all $k$) we have  $$\sqrt[n]{|z-a_1|\cdot|z-a_2|
>  \cdot\cdot\cdot |z-a_n|}$$ assumes a maximum value greater than $R$,
>   and a minimum value less than $R$ at some points $z$ on $|z| = R$.
>    Hint: Consider applying Maximum and Minimum Modulus to
>   $\prod_{k=1}^{n}(R^{2}-\overline{a_k}z)$

a) I would assume the question meant that $R>1$. Now to show $f(z) = \left|\dfrac{R(z-a)}{R^{2}-\overline{a}z}\right|$ is analytic in $|z| \leq R$, it suffices to check the denominators of $f$ are outside the range of $|z| = R$. Indeed, the pole $z = \dfrac{R^{2}}{\overline{a}}$ is outside the circle, as one can verify with $$\dfrac{|R^{2}|}{|\overline{a}|} > \dfrac{|R^{2}|}{R} = R$$

Next, we verify that the function $f$ indeed serves as a mapping from $|z| =R$ to $|z|=1$. It suffices to show that for $|a| < R$ and for all $|z| = R$, we have $|f(z)| = 1$.

To show $|f(z)| =1 1$, it suffices to show $\left|R(z-a)\right|^{2} -|R^{2}-\overline{a}z|^{2} = 0$ on $|z| = R$ and $|a| < R$.

After expanding out,

$\begin{aligned}
\left|R(z-a)\right|^{2} -|R^{2}-\overline{a}z|^{2}  & = R(z-a)\cdot R(\overline{z}-\overline{a}) - (R^{2}-\overline{a}z)(R^{2}-a\overline{z})\\
  &= R^{2}(z\overline{z}-z\overline{a}-a\overline{z}+a\overline{a})- (R^{4}-R^{2}a\overline{z}-\overline{a}zR^{2}+a\overline{a}z\overline{z})\\
  &= R^{4}-R^{2}\overline{a}z-R^{2}a\overline{z}+R^{2}|a|^{2}-R^{4}+R^{2}a\overline{z}+R^{2}\overline{a}z-|a|^{2}R^{2}\\
  &= R^{4}R^{2}|a|^{2}-R^{4}-|a|^{2}R^{2}\\
  &= R^{4}-R^{4} =0 \\
  &< 0
\end{aligned}$

Hence we have verified part a).

b) We need to show $$\left|\left(|z-a_1|\cdot |z-a_2| \cdot \cdot \cdot |z-a_n|\right)^{n}\right| < (R+\epsilon_1)$$

On $|z| = R$, we have $$\left|\dfrac{R(z-a_1)\cdot R(z-a_2) \cdot\cdot\cdot R(z-a_n)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(R^{2}-\overline{a_k}z\right)}\right| = 1 ~~~\text{ by part a) }$$

By simplifying, we have $$|z-a_1|\cdot |z-a_2| \cdot\cdot\cdot |z-a_n| = \left|\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(R^{2}-\overline{a_k}z\right)}{R^{n}}\right|$$

$\left|\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(R^{2}-\overline{a_k}z\right)\right| = \left|\prod_{k=1}^{n}R^{2}\left(1-\dfrac{\overline{a_k}z}{R^{2}}\right)\right| \leq R^{2n}\left|\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\overline{a_k}\right)\right|$

Thus it follows that $$|z-a_1|\cdot |z-a_2| \cdot\cdot\cdot |z-a_n| = \left|\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(R^{2}-\overline{a_k}z\right)}{R^{n}}\right| \leq R^{n}\left|\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\overline{a_k}\right)\right|$$

> For part $a)$, i am not even sure if i am right, can anyone please
>   verify. For part b), i have some clue, but i cannot get to apply the
>   max/min modulus principle hence there must be something wrong.
>   Furthermore, the question says that it assumes a maximum value greater
>   than $R$, however, my proof can only show that it is bounded by some
>   bound and not really answering the question.
>
> Please help me, it is from Bak and newman, chapter 7.

Comment: In (a) you seem to have assumed that $z\overline z=R$ somewhere in the calculation. I also see no reason to assume $R>1$.

Comment: Since it says map the circle $|z| = R$, so we are considering the values of $z$ on the boundary $|z| = R$, yea for the $R>1$ part i am not very sure.

Comment: It is **not** true that $z\overline z=R$ on the circle. What actually is it?

Comment: oh it is $R^{2}$

Comment: Then there will be a problem, as it cancels out and becomes $0$.

Comment: Ok, then there will be no problem, as now the part a actually means it is mapping the boundary of $|z| = R$ to the boundary of $|z| = 1$.

Comment: A complex function taking only real numbers as values is analytic only if it is constant.

Comment: @egreg Can you elaborate a bit more, or direct me thanks

Comment: @ilovewt The function you want to show is analytic is $f(z)=\frac{R(z-a)}{R^2-\bar{a}z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for part A seems to be correct, although there are likely shorter ways to do it.

For part B, I think the answer you are looking for is here:
[Show that $\sqrt[k]{|z-a_1|\cdots |z-a_k|}$ has a max greater than $R$, and a min less than $R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302606/show-that-sqrtkz-a-1-cdots-z-a-k-has-a-max-greater-than-r-and-a-mi?rq=1)

You don't actually need to convert $z = e^{\theta i} $ form.

Let $f(z) = \left| z - a _ { 1 } \right| \cdot \left| z - a _ { 2 } \right| \cdots \left| z - a _ { n } \right|$. You want to show that there exists a point in $|z| \leq R$ where $f(z) = R$. For instance, $f(0)$. If you plug $z = 0$ into $\prod _ { k = 1 } ^ { n } \left( R ^ { 2} - \overline { a _ { k } } z \right)$ since they are equivalent expressions, you will find that $|R^n|f(0) = \prod _ { k = 1 } ^ { n }  R ^ { 2 } = R^{2n} \implies f(0) = R^n$. So the function you care about is $g(z) = f(z)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, which means that $g(0) = R$. $z = 0$, however is not the boundary. So by Min/Max Mod Theorem, there must be a minimum or a maximum on the boundary such that it is less than/greater than $R$ and we are done.